# Why does my network feature is disabled?

Tags: internet

Both the Wifi and the ethernet connection to the internet are not working. All had been functioning fine until the Ubuntu suspended itself. On re-starting, the connection to internet failed to function and now I get the message "Network Disabled" whenever I re-boot.

nm-tool tells me the state is "asleep". Stopping and starting the NetworkManager has no effect

The machine is an Inspiron 9300 and work perfectly with Windows.
How do I wake the networking up?

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

Ahh, the good old NM bug.

stop network-manager

`sudo rm /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state`

start network-manager

Scream bloody murder if this fixes the issue. (This really should have been fixed a long time ago)

Comment: Thank you. Worked a treat. I wasted quit a few hours on this one and almost considered going back to Windows.

Comment: I've just encountered this one with Ubuntu 13.10, and these instructions fixed it for me. *thumbsup* (I had also manually forced it back up with `ifconfig eth0 up` and `dhclient eth0`, but of course that's not the right way as it bypasses all the management.)

Comment: This problem is still present in Ubuntu 14.04 - and your answer worked just fine. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I skipped the second command (`sudo rm /var/lib...`) and it still solved the issue for my Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on VMWare.

Answer (score 0):

For `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo rm /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
sudo service network-manager start
```

For `Ubuntu 21.04`:

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
sudo rm /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service
```

If it does still not work. change your `NetworkManager.conf` file, and change the `managed` is `true` if it was false.

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

restart your Network manager service

```
$ service network-manager restart
```